# How can I create an API Gateway end point with a dynamic URI using the AWS CDK in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Is there a possibility to set a dynamic URI in the AWS API_GATEWAY aws_cdk description?

I currently have:

```
    integration=api_gateway.Integration(
            type=_apigw.IntegrationType.HTTP,
            integration_http_method='GET',
            uri=my_uri+'/my_service/my_fixed_endpoint',
            ...
```

Now I would like to use something like:

```
uri=my_uri+'/my_service/{my_dynamic_endpoint}',
```

With `{my_dynamic_endpoint}` being replaced with e.g. "football", "baseball", "tennis".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question in line with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If I've made mistakes in understanding your problem, please feel free & do re-edit your question. I'd recommend giving that page a read for any future questions you would like to ask :)

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. How would the API handle this arbitrary endpoint?

Comment: If you want to do this in order to re-use code / create a helper function so you can create multiple apis and end points - then pretty much exactly as you have with any kind of string formation (`f'{some_var} in my string`' in python). If  you have some other use case in mind, we need more information

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer in the aws api gateway docs. There, they use the following example:

```
api = apigateway.RestApi(self, "books-api")

api.root.add_method("ANY")

book = books.add_resource("{book_id}")
book.add_method("GET")
book.add_method("DELETE")
```

So I should write it in an object based manner like that

```
api = apigateway.RestApi(self, "sports-api")

api.root.add_method("ANY")

book = books.add_resource("{sport}")
book.add_method("GET")
book.add_method("DELETE")
```

What I called "my_dynamic_endpoint" is just a variable in the url path.

Sorry for the misleading formulations!!!

Comment: Finally en explaination. I was getting mad thinking about the utter defiance of f-string formatting principles. Thanks